# Parsing parameters into CircleCI workflow from UI

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-workflows

I am running the below command in my config.yml

```
terraform import aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment.<< pipeline.parameters.account_assignment >> << pipeline.parameters.account_assignment_params >>
```

For `pipeline.parameters.account_assignment` , I am passing the value as -

```
AWSAdministratorAccess["304939220200"]
```

However, it is read as below (without the quotes):

```
aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment.AWSAdministratorAccess[304939220200]
```

How to have the value passed with the quotes in the parameter via the `Trigger Pipeline` option?